# React Native useEffect() re-renders too much

Tags: react-native

i have a useEffect function where a redux action is called and data is written to prop. My Problem is that useEffect loop many times and flooded the server with requests.

```
const { loescherData, navigation } = props;

useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userdata').then((userdata) => {
        if (userdata) {
            console.log(new Date());
            console.log(userdata);
            var user = JSON.parse(userdata);
            props.fetchLoescherDetails(user.standort);
            setData(props.loescherData);
        }
    });
}, [loescherData]);
```

if i leave it blank the rendering is finished before receiving data and the content would not updated.
is there another way to work with this function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`loescherData` won't be available right after calling your redux-action `fetchLoescherDetails` ... and changing component by `setData` will cause an infinite rendering cause your current `useEffect` has a dependency on `loescherData`

So I'd suggest you exec your redux-action `onComponentDidMount` by passing an empty-deps `[]` to your effect ... and then consume the output of you action in a different `effect`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userdata').then((userdata) => {
      if (userdata) {
        console.log(new Date());
        console.log(userdata);
        var user = JSON.parse(userdata);
        props.fetchLoescherDetails(user.standort);
        // setData(props.loescherData);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loescherData) {
      //  do some with loescherData like setState
    }
  }, [loescherData]);
```

Comment: That works as expected. Thx. To my understanding: the first useEffect (!with empty Callback) is like ComponentDidMount() and the 2nd method calls as long as `loescherData` have no data. After receiving data rerendering stop? Is this correct?

Comment: `useEffect(() => {}, [loescherData])` executes whenever a new value for `loescherData` is received